# Retrieve images and text from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am about create an android app. The idea of the app is very easy but I faced problems in implementation because I am new. The app name will be Food Description.

It will contain a button, when you press the button a list of images will show about each food. For example chicken, meet, etc. These imaged should be store in firebase manually. When I press any image it should give me a detailed description about the food. This description is also should save in firebase manually.

The questions are:

- How can I create a database contain image and description?
- How can I retrieve the stored images list with their description?

Comment: Ahmed, I think you need to use Realtime Firebase Database. It's really easy to use. this tutorial is very helpfull to learn about Fireabse. It has been used old libs. You need to use last version libs. So you will need to change some codes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1RUOexThGs&t=878s Any question let me know! Happy codes!

Comment: Please provide what have you done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

1. Create a project in Firebase with the same package name as of android project you are building.
2. Select the project then follow the below steps for storing Image:

   - Go to Storage.
   - Add your images in store by Clicking Upload Files.
   - When you complete uploading images then you will get Download URL of each image. This is what you need to get Image.
3. Go to database:

   - Create a database, lets say `food`.
   - Put your Food information as you want in DB, you need to give a unique value of each food.
   - Then for each food, put the key-value pair as, {name, image, description}. Here name will be food name, description is food description, for Images, just put the download URL from storage.

Now in Android Project.

Make a POJO model Class for Food like below

```
Class Food {
   public String name;
   public String Image;
   public String description;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public String getImage() {
       return image;
   }
   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }
}
```

Get list of Foods using following code.

```
Firebase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("foods");

mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Food food = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
        ArrayList<Food> foodsList = new ArrayList<>();

       foodsList.add(food);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

Your can set Image using Glide or picaso

like below

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load(foodsList.get(index).getImage()).into(imageView);
```

Please follow steps from here to learn how to embed data from firebase to RecyclerView

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpObpZ5MYSE

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did all the steps written but when I tried to write POJO class an error appeared "incorrect structure". And also I did not know the other codes location is it in the button or somewhere else? and how the record in the firebase will be connected to text and image view. sorry for that because i am new in android and dont have an exoerence.

Comment: You need to call the firebase `addValueEventListener` in `OnCreate` method of the activity
This will give you data in `foodsList` Array, then you can put data in either `RecyclerView` or `ListView`.

Comment: Really I can't get it theoretically, is there a video explain the steps?

Comment: I have updated my answer, There is a URL to learn how to embed data in RecyclerView. Please look into that

Answer (score 0):

export your firebase datastructure from database menu exported file will comes in json. remember copy only food tree structure of that json and paste it to [json to pojo convertor](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) rest thing is same as mentioned by bhuvensh.